# OpenCV SVM Multiple class training c++

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I'm trying to train a set of images divided into 8 classifiers.

I've found many answers about how to train SVM but most of them (kinda all of them) are only using 1-2 classes.

Here is what I did so far (Note that it just crash without giving me an error):

```
int num_files = 128;
std::ifstream       file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);


int img_area = 200 * 200;

float labels[128];
Mat faceMatReshaped[128];
int incr = 0;
Mat                     image; //original immage
Mat                     roi;//Region Of Interest in the image a.k.a the detected face
Size                    size(200, 200);//the dst image size
string                  line, path, classlabel; //current line, image path, image label number
while (getline(file, line))
{
    stringstream        liness(line);
    getline(liness, path, ';');
    getline(liness, classlabel);

    if (!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty())
    {
        image = imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        //image = imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

        vector< Rect_<int> > faces_c;

        haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, faces_c); //detect face on the sample

        if (faces_c.size() > 0)
        {
            roi = Mat(image, faces_c[0]);
            Mat                     dst;//dst image

            resize(roi, dst, size);//resize image
            faceMatReshaped[incr] = dst.reshape(0, 1);

            labels[incr] = (float)atoi(classlabel.c_str());
        }
        else
            std::cout << "PASSED: " << path << std::endl;
        incr++;
    }

}
Mat labelsmat(128, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

labelsmat.convertTo(labelsmat, CV_32FC1);

Mat new_image(128, img_area, CV_32FC1, faceMatReshaped); //CONVERT TO 32FC1

CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::POLY;
params.gamma = 3;
params.degree = 3;
params.coef0 = 0;

params.C = 7;
params.nu = 0.0;
params.p = 0.0;

    //Crash here
svm.train(new_image, labelsmat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

I think that's my label array that may be wrong but I'm not sure.

EDIT:

I tested the labelsmat using this piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<labelsmat.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j<labelsmat.cols; j++)
        printf("labels(%d, %d) = %f \n", i, j, labelsmat.at<float>(i, j));
```

Basically I get this:
    From class 0 to 7 (so 8 class in total)
    From 0 to 127 (128 rows)

The labels seems correct the only one left I guess is the 1D Mat then. How can I check if it's correct or not ?

[image: Result]

Comment: labels should be integers, not floats. Try changing to the line to: `labelsmat.convertTo(labelsmat, CV_32SC1);`

Comment: Changed it to labelsmat.convertTo(labelsmat, CV_32SC1); still crashing w/o error code. (I also changed labels to integers)

Comment: make sure number of features should be the same and label type CV_32S. tested and works fine.